# How to modify regex for date format?

Tags: regex, powershell

I got this from [/r/sysadmin](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/) on Reddit, but the date format is different since the dude is from Europe and he used a Regular Expression, which I am fairly new to using.

The array which is filled using the RegEx as a filter is coming up empty since the RegEx is incorrect and the line where the DateTime format is set is coming up with an error stating that the string is invalid.

I tried changing the DateTime format from `dd.MM.yyyy` to `M.d.yyyy`
and then matching the RegEx, but it was probably wrong.

```bsh
# Determine user's last logon time
# The script reads the output of "query.exe user" and parses the date 
# and time returned by it using a regular expression.
# ADJUST: Make sure to change the regular expression to match your date format.
$query = query.exe user $env:username
($user, $logon, $matches) = ($null, $null, $null)

foreach ($line in $query) 
{
    $temp = $line -match '^\>([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+).*((\d{1}\.){1}\d{4}\ \d{2}\:\d{2})$'
}
$user = $matches[1]
$last_logon = $matches[2]

$getdt = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat
$DateFormat = $getdt.ShortDatePattern
$TimeFormat = $getdt.ShortTimePattern
$DateTimeFormat = '$DateFormat $TimeFormat'

# This calculates the timespan between NOW and the last time the user logged in

# ADJUST: Make sure the date format matches your locale
$last_logon_duration = (New-TimeSpan –Start ([datetime]::ParseExact($last_logon, `
    'M.d.yyyy HH:mm', $null)) -End (Get-Date))
```

I am expecting it to put the Username in `$user`, the DateTime in `$last_logon`, and for the DateTime format to be recognized as valid.

```
At Z:\Adrian\Ticket Items\Projects\30 Day reboots\Reboots.ps1:96 char:1
+ $user = $matches[1]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Cannot index into a null array.
At Z:\Adrian\Ticket Items\Projects\30 Day reboots\Reboots.ps1:97 char:1
+ $last_logon = $matches[2]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray 

Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At Z:\Adrian\Ticket Items\Projects\30 Day reboots\Reboots.ps1:104 char:1
+ $last_logon_duration = (New-TimeSpan –Start ([datetime]::ParseExact($ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

Comment: `((\d{1}\.){1}\d{4}\ \d{2}\:\d{2})` -> `(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4} \d{2}\:\d{2})`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers you should lazy match the `.*` to `.*?`, else the first digit in months November and December will never match

Comment: @AutomatedChaos True. My bad.

Comment: Off topic: You'll need to change this `$DateTimeFormat = '$DateFormat $TimeFormat'` to `$DateTimeFormat = "$DateFormat $TimeFormat"` if you expect the [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6#single-and-double-quoted-strings) to work.

Comment: are you interested in  a function to convert the output of `query/quser` to a PoSh  custom object? it converts the output to CSV layout and uses that instead of regex. if you want it posted as an answer here, please ask ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for the offer, but I don't need it currently. This is just a script to prompt people to restart their computers if they have been active for longer than 30 days

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. I will test it and see how it goes

Comment: @a3yko -  you are welcome ... and good luck with your project! [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match `M.dd.yyyy` you should change the regex to:
`^\>([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+).*?(1?\d\.\d\d.\d\d\d\d \d\d\:\d\d)$`

See [this regex101 entry](https://regex101.com/r/sluhFj/2)

I explicitly got rid of the `{...}` expressions so it makes it more clear to you what it is doing.